# Error in getting current country

Tags: iphone, locale

I am using following code to get current country

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCodes = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCodes];
NSLog(@"%@",countryName);
```

I am in UAE , but this is showing United States , I testing on my iPod , please help how Can I get current country ?

Comment: by any chance are you testing on simulator ?

Comment: Check once your iPod settings (Region Format).

Comment: @Narayana if i am changing the region format to arabic(UAE) , it converts language to arabic

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    NSLog(@"Detail is:--> %@",placemark);

    NSString *strCountry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current Cuntry %@",[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Country"]];

    NSLog(@"label detail is:--> %@",strCountry);

    lblAddress.text = strCountry;
}
```

Try this code...This will definately give you a current country detail.