# Open App on specific Tab depenging by Device System Language

Tags: ios, internationalization, tabbar

Can I open an iPhone TabBar App on a Tab or another depending on Language setted on Device?

For example: First Tab of my app is named "USA", second "Germany",  third "France". Is possible to open App directly on second Tab if device's language is setted on German or open App directly on third Tab if device's language is setted on French?

Comment: My TabBar hasn't a Controller, I made it just on Storyboard and it works!, so actually I haven't any UITabBarController or Array containing Tab's name. How could I implement this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a definitive "maybe".

As soon as your Default/launch screen disappears you'll end up on the view with the tab bar.  You then need to quickly switch to the language/country specific tab programatically, which you should be able to do in UIApplicationDelegate's "`application: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`" delegate method.  There's a decent chance the user might see the initial tab view before you do the switch.

You can get the user's preferred language via [`[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/preferredLanguages).

If you want to get the current country, [you'll need to use CLLocationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662966/error-in-getting-current-country).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the language of the device like this

```
[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can choose a particular tab in code like this

```
// if myTabViewController is a handle to the UITabViewController
int myTab = 2; // this is the tab that we want to display
myTabViewController.selectedIndex = myTab;
```